# Pass a config-node parameter within HTML-File to another node

Tags: html, node.js, node-red

I created following input-node:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
RED.nodes.registerType('Sensor',{
    category: 'input',
    defaults: {
        name: {type:"InputDevice", required:true},
        count: {value:"", required:true, validate:RED.validators.number()},
        topic: {value:"",validate: RED.validators.regex(/^(#$|(\+|[^+#]*)(\/(\+|[^+#]*))*(\/(\+|#|[^+#]*))?$)/)},
        qos: {value: "1"},
        broker: {type:"mqtt-broker", required:true},
    },
    color:"#3FADB5",
    inputs:0,
    outputs:1,
    icon: "feed.png",
    label: function() {
        //var testu = RED.nodes.getNode(config.name).inputDeviceName;
        //return this.name.inputDeviceName;
        return this.name||this.topic||"ClientName";
    },
    labelStyle: function() {
        return this.name?"node_label_italic":"";
    },
});
```

And following config node:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
RED.nodes.registerType('InputDevice',{
    category: 'config',
    defaults: {
        inputDeviceName: {value:"",required:true},
    },
    label: function() {
        return this.inputDeviceName;
    }
});
```

I can not figure out, how to pass over the parameter

> inputDeviceName

to my Sensor node within the HTML File. Within the JS File, i am able to get the value of inputDeviceName with:

```
this.name = RED.nodes.getNode(config.name).inputDeviceName;
```

[image: Edit Sensor Node Example]

How can I name the sensor-node, like in the example above, to appear as 'LDR' in my flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of any node for which you know the id in a HTML file with `RED.nodes.node(node_id)`. This will return this nodes default properties.

If you, for example, need some property from a config node, you can get its id from the value of the `select` HTML-element associated with the config node.